# What kind of codes can be into PDO transactions?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Here is my script:

```
$id    = $_GET['id'];
$value = $_GET['val'];

// database connection here

try{
    $db_conn->beginTransaction();
    // inserting
    $stm1 = $db_conn->prepare("INSERT into table1 (col) VALUES (?)");
    $stm1->execute(array($value));

    // updating
    $stm2 = $db_conn->prepare("UPDATE table2 SET col = "a new row inserted" WHERE id = ?");
    $stm2->execute(array($id));

    $db_conn->commit();
}
catch(PDOException $e){
    $db_conn->rollBack();
}
```

All I want to know, can I use an `if` statement in the codes which are between `beginTransaction()` and `commit()` ? Something like this:

```
$id    = $_GET['id'];
$value = $_GET['val'];

// database connection here

try{
    $db_conn->beginTransaction();
    // inserting
    $stm1 = $db_conn->prepare("INSERT into table1 (col) VALUES (?)");
    $stm1->execute(array($value));

    // updating
    if (/* a condition here */){
        $stm2 = $db_conn->prepare("UPDATE table2 SET col = "a new row inserted" WHERE id = ?");
        $stm2->execute(array($id));
    }

    $db_conn->commit();
}
catch(PDOException $e){
    $db_conn->rollBack();
}
```

Can I ?

---

Actually I asked that because [here](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.begintransaction.php) is a sentence which says you can't and doing that is dangerous:

> Won't work and is dangerous since you could close your transaction too early with the nested commit().

Comment: Read again the comment there. He said, nested transaction while you have only one.

Comment: @Chay22 I read it several times.. the problem is my poor English .. thank you anyway.

Comment: Ha, we have the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

There is no problem with your transaction structure. The comment on php.net only means, that MySQL does not support *nested* transactions. In order to your further question, you can query any data (SQL), manipulate *data* (DML), but **not** modify any database structures (DDL - data definition language).

```
/*won't work*/
START TRANSACTION;
/*statement*/
START TRANSACTION; /*nested not supported, auto commit*/
/*statement*/
COMMIT;
/*statement dependend on 1st transaction won't work*/
COMMIT;
```

See also [MySQL ref](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/implicit-commit.html)

> Transactions cannot be nested. This is a consequence of the implicit commit performed for any current transaction when you issue a START TRANSACTION statement or one of its synonyms.

Comment: Have to add, that only data queries are allowed in transactions. DDL queries, e.g alter table will cause a commit of open transactions before being executed by MySQL.

Comment: All `insert`, `update`, `select`, `delete` are fine?

Comment: Yes, in general they should - they could include function calls, triggers aso. where code could break things. I've fixed the URL to the MySQL ref. See for details.

Answer (score 1):

You can do everything within a transaction, the only thing you cannot do is nest transactions.

Not the `if` clause itself is the problem in your linked comment, but the fact there is another `beginTransaction` / `commit` pair inside.

Comment: So my second code (include `if` statement) is fine ?